# Security.salt issue

Tags: cakephp, configuration, cakephp-3.x

I have a docker container running PHP 7.2.14 and CakePHP 3.7.9

The problem I see is that for some reason Security.salt is empty.
This is a standard line in the app.php file:

```
'Security' => [
        'salt' => env('SECURITY_SALT', 'mySalt')
],
```

When I check the value in code with `Configure::read('Security.salt')` it is empty.
If I put `error_log(env('SECURITY_SALT', 'blah'));` I see `blah` in the log file. So that means `env()` is working correctly and the salt should be set to `mySalt`.

So is this a bug and somehow `Security.salt` gets overwritten? Or is that default behavior that is only used internally and set to null after it's read internally?

Answer (score 0):

> Or is that default behavior that is only used internally and set to null after it's read internally?

That's kinda how it works, yes.  Some configuration is being "consumed" at some point, in the 3.7 application template that by default is `Cache`, `Datasources`, `EmailTransport`, `Email`, `Log`, and `Security.salt`, see your applications `config/bootstrap.php` file.

**https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/3.7.1/config/bootstrap.php#L150-L155**

If you want to access such configuration at a later point, then you should access it via the classes that consumed it, in your case the `Security` class, ie read it via

```
\Cake\Utility\Security::getSalt()
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Configuration > Configure Class > Reading & Deleting Configuration Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#reading-deleting-configuration-data)**
- **[API > \Cake\Core\Configure::consume()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.7/class-Cake.Core.Configure.html#_consume)**
- **[API > \Cake\Utility\Security::getSalt()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.7/class-Cake.Utility.Security.html#_getSalt)**